# LaTeX command for double lower index summation

Tags: equations

I would like to know what is the latex command to include a double lower index using sigma notation (i.e: second index lies underneath the first index)?

I tried typing:

```
\displaystyle\sum_{m,n=-\infty, \; (m,n)\neq (0,0)}^{\infty}
\left[
  \frac{1}{(z-2 m\omega_{1} - 2 n\omega_{2})^{2}}
 -\frac{1}{   4(m\omega_{1} +   n\omega_{2})^{2}}
\right]
```

I would appreciate the assistance. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add some context? What's `\dsy`, for instance?

Comment: Hi Greg. \dsy means displaystyle for the sigma sign

Comment: You *don't* need `\displaystyle`; if your formula is inline, use `\sum\limits` (or simply `\sum`, which is better).

Answer (score 6):

The `\substack` command from the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package can do what you are after:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{\substack{m,n=-\infty,\\(m,n)\neq (0,0)}}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{(z-2 m\omega_{1}-2 n\omega_{2})^{2}}-\frac{1}{4(m\omega_{1}+n\omega_{2})^{2}}\right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

Or without the comma, since the next condition is on a new line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{\substack{m,n=-\infty\\(m,n)\neq (0,0)}}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{(z-2 m\omega_{1}-2 n\omega_{2})^{2}}-\frac{1}{4(m\omega_{1}+n\omega_{2})^{2}}\right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments and i appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `substack`:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

...

\begin{equation}
  \prod_{\substack{
    1 \le i \le n \\
    1 \le j \le m} }
  M_{i,j}
\end{equation}
```

This example is taken from the [Latex Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Multiline_subscripts).